# Issue with deploying Microsoft azure template (CSP frontstore)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

first of all the readme.md need to be updated as this part is different `Build & Deploy on your own`

Now I have tried to deploy through the deploy to azure button

I got this error

```
Deployment to resource group 'new-test' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
```

tried to deploy with visual studio 2019 got the same thing
following this article (which was out of date)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/iwilliams/reseller-storefront

after the second attempt it built successfully (just did redeploy without any modifications)

but still got the default page with this text

```
Hey, App Service developers!

Your app service is up and running.
Time to take the next step and deploy your code.
```

tried to publish by the publish option in visual studio

filled all the option `Web.config`

did not find any option that says secret key to fill
 publish succeeded, opened the site got the following message in the browser

```
[AdalServiceException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).]
   Microsoft.Identity.Core.OAuth2.<GetResponseAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory\Core\OAuth2\OAuthClient.cs:66

[AdalServiceException: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.
Trace ID: 6c8d61c0-69fd-45b0-a796-6e20a4b83500
Correlation ID: bfd2304e-86f4-4b0d-b1d7-409c7a1db9aa
Timestamp: 2020-04-27 01:06:26Z]
```

Comment: Follow the step of tutorial, I have modify the code, but the program runs wrong and other users report errors. So I search the lastest document about it which I have updated in my answer. Hope it useful to u.

Comment: I have tried the sample you attached, but this is some thing different, this desktop app not web app